# Spring Boot with mysql containerization

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose, communication

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost" ]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: poc
    ports:
      - 8500:3306
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql

  redis-to-mysql:
    image: redis-to-mysql:1
    hostname: redis-to-mysql
    ports:
      - "8400:8400"
    environment:
      spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:8500/poc?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
      spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
      spring.datasource.username: root
      spring.datasource.password: root
      spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: none
    depends_on:
      mysqldb:
        condition: service_healthy

volumes:
  db:

Description:
```

Using above docker-compose I am getting a connection refused due to a communication link error.

Earlier I was using custom network

```
    networks:
     app:
      driver: bridge
```

Also tried using different dialect provided for mysql8.Trying this on Mac M1 machine. Also tried with arm64 vesion of mysql8 and got similar error.

Comment: @mahfuj asif  Thank you for editing. Please let me know how did you do that.

Comment: I found the issue. I was not supposed to put port number in the the datasource url:

intead of  spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:8500/poc?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true 

use

spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://mysqldb/poc?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true

Comment: check this question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Also follow this guideline to avoid downvotes https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think mysql allow root access from localhost by default. You could consider from this perspective and let you mysql could be access from any host. Something like

mysql> update mysql.user set host = '%' where user='root';

FYI: https://nemoz.info/run-mysql-from-docker-and-allow-access-from-outside-container/